# Efficiently taking out Sentry Guns in Call of Duty Black Ops?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

What are the most efficient ways to take out sentry guns in Call of Duty black ops?  I know these work:

- Rocket Launcher
- Knife

I assume ammo, if you live long enough?  Grenades probably, maybe a couple tacticals?

Thanks.

Comment: Er... doesn't anything that deal damage eventually destroy a turret?

Comment: OK, let me clarify: more efficient solutions.

Comment: Then edit your question accordingly :)

Comment: I removed the wii tag because it applies across all gaming platforms

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are talking about the `Sentry Gun` then the following tactics apply

1. Use a flash / stun grenade and then knife it
2. Change to your side with Hacker Pro
3. Use a ballistic knife / tomahawk
4. Deal 1000 points of damage ( it has 0.3X armour ) with bullets [ http://www.mw2forum.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=17071 ]

If you are talking about `SAM Turret` then almost the same tactics apply.

They have 1000 hit points as well and can be stunned in the same manner. ( this might be useful because 'poorly' placed SAM Turrets can kill ground targets by shooting into walls etc. ) Hacker Pro can also be used. But since they are otherwise defenseless, just walk over and knife them

Answer (score 1):

The safest way to deal with turrets is getting behind it (if necessary, use a flash/stun to disable it first) and knifing.

If you are in grenade proximity and have a clear view to it, then you might throw a flash/stun grenade to disable it briefly, then throw a frag/semtex, and then shooting at it. You will need to unload about least a magazine from an LMG or a couple of them if you have an assault rifle.

If you can get closer than that, you could also throw your C4 next to it and blow it up, without even getting caught in its fire.

Remember, you can only pull this off if you live long enough and the only option iis frontal attack.
You can safely forget this on hardcore, though: one or two turret hits put an end to your already short life.

A more orthodox way of dealing with a sentry is hacking it with the Hacker Pro perk. This way, you can hack it and it becomes yours. You still need to approach it from behind though.

Answer (score 1):

With `Hacker` you can see it through cover, with `Hardened` you can shoot it through light cover. It's especially efficient with `Hardened Pro` (+25% damage to turrets) and LMGs.

Answer (score 0):

Since you ask what is the most efficient way, here's my answer.

In terms of efficiency, you want to use the solution that's the least cost to you but the most cost to the enemy.

Hence, knife it. You don't waste ammo, and the enemy is one sentry gun down.

Any other way (RPG / M72 Law / Guns) will end up in you wasting ammo you could have used to rack up a killstreak and you probably won't be instantly successful like you would be with a knife.

Another reason for knifing it: Once the enemy places a sentry gun in a certain area, they tend to ignore that part of the map thinking the sentry gun will take care of it. Hence, you'd be safer going to the sentry gun and knifing it out rather than gunning it down from a different part of the map. Shooting at it makes you show up on the radar, too.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense though ypu typically need to use a tactical to get near it, if it's not in a good sneak up location.

Comment: i don't think i will ignore my sentry gun, i use it as method to cover a potential choke while I camp >:D

Comment: @Brian - True, though till date I've usually been successful enough to sneak up behind them without using any equipment. Maybe I've never come across any situation where I would need a tactical... yet.        @bronzebeard - You camper! Shame on you! *shakes head*

Answer (score 0):

Sentry guns should be approached from it's flank. You can stun it with a flash-bang. Knife it to save ammo. SAM Turrets are easy, just run up and knife it.

Answer (score 0):

you throw smoke at the sentry and then go up and knife it.